# GGPlot2 - Sum the y values at each X, for multi-panel plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code:

qplot(year, Emissions, data = baltimore, facets = .~type)

I get this graph:
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcjzn.png)

The only change I want to do is to sum the x points at each y value. When I try doing sum(Emissions) I just get identical x points for everything (presumably it's just summing all x regardless of y). When I try cumsum(Emissions) for my x value I still have multiple points.

How do I preserve my plot, with just the change of getting a total of the x values for each y instead of individual points?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: As @RonakShah mentioned, reproducible data would be helpful here. You can provide your data using `dput()`. You can provide minimal data with something like `dput(head(df))`.